# Error when adding into Collection of ArrayList (IndexOutofBoundsException)

Tags: anylogic

I have a collection of ArrayList of int. It's intended to keep track whether a berth is used and whether the ship has left. As I understand from AnyLogic reference, we can add element to collection of ArrayList by invoking add and the ArrayList is allowed to grow in length. But when I do the following

```
            berth_idx = permNAtt.size()-1; // should be 4 max
            indixlist.add(berth_idx, agent.shipindex)
```

I got the below error:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
Index: 3, Size: 2
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
```

The size of the indixlist is 2 and the berth_idx is 3.

I think this error shouldn't happen because the ArrayList should be able to grow. So perhaps fresh pairs of eyes can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why you are adding to location and not just adding to the end?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to add members to a collection (even if it is not defined as an ArrayList).

The error you got comes when you try to add a member in an index out of range.
if you have 2 members in the list then the new member must go between 0 and 2, it cannot go in index 3 (which is member 4).

Try the following code:

```
indixlist.add(indixlist.size(), agent.shipindex);
```